# Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly

Tags: magento2

In **Magento ver. 2.2.4** when I try to make a payment with a credit card or by Bank Transfer this exception is generated. With PayPal this does not happen and I can place orders without problems.

> 2018-07-11 13:50:40] main.CRITICAL: Rolled back transaction has not
>   been completed correctly. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0):
>   Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly. at
>   /home/wwwdos9/public_html/.../vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:270)"}

Comment: Now show me other error.  Unique constraint violation found

Comment: Can you show the full error?

Comment: I do not get more information either in debug.log, or in exception.log or in system.log. Where can I see the transaction that is generating the error?

Comment: Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1200022450-1' for key 'SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT INTO sales_order (state, status, protect_code, shipping_description, is_virtual, store_id, customer_id, base_discount_amount, base_grand_total, base_shipping_amount, base_shipping_tax_amount, base_subtotal, base_tax_amount, base_to_global_rate, base_to_order_rate, discount_amount, grand_total, shipping_amount, shipping_tax_amount, store_to_base_rate

Comment: If you remove this order `1200022450-1` from sales_order table, it should solve the problem.

Comment: The strange thing is that the last order is 1200023039 so the next should be the 1200023040 and not the 1200022450 so I would have to delete also the 51.52 .... more than 80 orders to not give this error. In Eav_entity_store_ide the last increment id is the correct 1200023039

Comment: @JuanDosil can you help me on this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293795/rolled-back-transaction-has-not-been-completed-correctly-while-saving-product please

Answer (score 0):

This error is regrading in 'banktransfer' extension in some database transaction performing on order time.

Things to check

- This error generally said that, your code is breaking database operation.
- Make sure saving data is properly loaded with that model.
- Note that save method is particularly calling model which you are loaded to save data.

This is the things you have to keep in mind.
I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: hello @Himanshu. I am facing this issue when i try to place the order using sagepay payment method

Comment: @Manjunath which event is calling please try to use *_commit_after event

Comment: yes, I checked in the sagepay module, they are using this event, "checkout_submit_all_after"

Comment: @Himanshu can you help me on this issue please https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293795/rolled-back-transaction-has-not-been-completed-correctly-while-saving-product

Answer (score 0):

We have been experiencing this issue across all of our Magento 2 sites. For us, switching off persistent cart (Store > Configuration > Customer > Persistent Shopping Cart) solved the issue. I really hope Magento can fix persistent cart, though, as we'd like to be able to use it again.